# QML Text: how to use CSS properties, e.g. text-decoration: overline

Tags: qt, text, qml, label, richtext

Is it possible to use CSS properties in QML Text or QML Label element? I am interested in `text-decoration: overline` and I want to mix overlined characteres with plain characters. I know I can put separate Text element for every character and use `font.overline: true`, but this is impractical solution.

Hence, how to write out "*a b *c *d" in such a way that a, c, and d are overlined instead of being prefixed with asterisk.

By the way, it is simple with underline, just use `<u>` and `</u>`, but this does not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean CSS inline in the text? Then yes. If you mean applying CSS to QML elements (as if they were HTML), then no (which I find ironic :).

Example adapted from the Qt [Text demo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-text.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.3
Pane  {
    id: root
    width: 480
    height: 320
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        color: "#272822"
  }
  Column {
        spacing: 20
        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            text: '<font color="white">I am the <b>very</b> model of' +
                         '<p>a <span style="text-decoration: overline">modern</span> ' +
                         '<i>major general</i>!</p></font>'
            font.pointSize: 14
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }
  }
}
```

I specifically needed to set `textFormat: Text.RichText`, with `Text.StyledText` the overline didn't work.

[image]

Comment: This works. Mostly. On Sailfish OS I noticed some bugs if you combine this with *font.capitalization: Font.SmallCaps*

Comment: Thanks for the `RichText` note

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using CSS inline with `style="..."` attributes of HTML elements, it is also possible in QML Text objects to use CSS classes. [Maxim's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58145177) would then look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
Pane  {
    id: root
    width: 480
    height: 320
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        color: "#272822"
    }
    Column {
        spacing: 20
        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            text: '
                <html>
                    <head><style>
                        p.white   { color: white; }
                        .overline { text-decoration: overline; }
                    </style></head>
                    <body>
                        <p class="white">I am the very model of a 
                            <span class="overline">modern</span> major general!
                        </p>
                    </body>
                </html>
            '
            font.pointSize: 14
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }
  }
}
```

Tested with Qt 5.12.